# Storing/recreating sensitive env variables after push to github

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, environment-variables, github-actions

In my NodeJS app I keep (sensitive) environment variables in a nodemon.json file which is added to .gitignore.
My issue is where to store environment variables for development after pushing to my github repo. I see two basic options:

1. Keep a local copy.
   This seems sub-optimal for a couple of reasons. Is it common practice?
2. Store env variables in the cloud.
   This option would be preferable but how to restore them locally?

Ideally I want to recreate the .env/nodemon.json file automatically when I clone the repo from github. Is this possible? I know (a bit) about github secrets and actions. Is that the way to go? Will I  need a third party service like Vault as well/instead? Or do I need a container like Docker maybe?

The app is currently deployed to an AWS EC2 instance. In production I ssh into the instance, clone the project and add a .env file manually. The project has dotenv installed.

Comment: Typically, you want your application to read environment variables. Locally, those might be sourced from `.env.local` and when building/deploying in Actions, you would create the environment variables from secrets at the respective steps.

Comment: I suppose .env.local is added to .gitignore and kept locally?
Ideally I find a solution which allows me to not keep a local copy of the project or any of it's files.

Comment: `In production I ssh into the instance, clone the project and add a .env file manually`. If you are already doing it that way in *production* (and don't plan to change) I would go the same way here as well with Github Actions: storing the env.json file content in a secret, creating the file from the secret value in the workflow and adding it manually wherever you want after cloning the repo, before performing the operation that will need it.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I would like to automate it. As stated in OP, ideally I create the file on a 'clone repo' action. Not sure if that is a valid GH event but even if it is, I suppose that would be the same for anyone cloning the repo. 

Maybe the second best solution for now is, as you say, storing the env.json data in a secret, then write that secret to a file on some 'low impact' event, eg issue_comment or discussion_comment?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to write an action/a job which downloads the created file with the secret onto my local machine?

Comment: I don't think it is possible (or at least not trivial without having a server running on your local machine to receive the request). What event would be the ideal solution for your workflow to run? (which would create the file after cloning the repo and running the commands using the file?)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there are multiple solutions for this using encryption.
git-secrets seems to be one of the more popular and better maintained ones. It uses GPG for encryption. Installation and setup is fairly easy - took me about 10 mins using their guide.
https://git-secret.io/